# Truncated image using matplotlib.pyplot with Python 3 running on Windows 10 and Jupyter NB

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I was trying to get a feel for the basic syntax structure of the code for the Mandelbrot set on Python, and came across [this online resource](https://youtu.be/gECmGwD0DaI). The code calls (optionally) for the package `numba`, which I don't have installed, although I doubt this is the problem.

The issue is that the output image is this:

[image]

as opposed to the expected picture:

[image]

so it truly looks like a very zoomed in, low resolution segment of the expected image.

The code that I ran (from the youtube video) is:

```
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mandelbrot(Re, Im, max_iter):
    C = complex(Re,Im)
    z= 0.0j

    for i in range(max_iter):
        z= z*z + C
        if(z.real * z.real + z.imag * z.imag) >= 4:
            return i

        return max_iter

columns = 2000 
rows = 2000

result = numpy.zeros([rows,columns]) 
for row_index, Re in enumerate(numpy.linspace(-2,1,num=rows)):
    for column_index, Im in enumerate(numpy.linspace(-1,1,num=columns)):
        result[row_index, column_index]= mandelbrot(Re, Im, 100)

plt.figure(dpi=100) 
plt.imshow(result.T,cmap='hot',interpolation='bilinear', extent=[-2,1,-1,1]) 
plt.xlabel('Re') 
plt.ylabel('Im') 
plt.show()
```

> Is the problem in the plotting parameters? If so, any suggestions?

---

After the accepted answer, here is the corrected code, ready to copy, paste and run:

```
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mandelbrot(Re, Im, max_iter):
    C = complex(Re,Im)
    z= 0.0j

    for i in range(max_iter):
        z= z*z + C
        if(z.real * z.real + z.imag * z.imag) >= 4:
            return i

    return max_iter

columns = 2000 
rows = columns

re1 = 0.0070
re2 = 0.0085
im1 = -.74770
im2 = -.74600

result = numpy.zeros([rows,columns]) 
for row_index, Re in enumerate(numpy.linspace(re1,re2,num=rows)):
    for column_index, Im in enumerate(numpy.linspace(im1,im2,num=columns)):
        result[row_index, column_index]= mandelbrot(Re, Im, 200)

plt.figure(dpi=150) 
plt.imshow(result.T,cmap='plasma',interpolation='bilinear', extent=[re1,re2,im1,im2]) 
plt.xlabel('Re') 
plt.ylabel('Im') 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please check your indentation? The code as it is currently, will not produce any output and it is crucial to see which parts are part of which loops.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I think it should run - it does on my laptop by simply copying and pasting after correcting indentations.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried installing 'numba' through the anaconda manager, and it seems at the root environment, yet the NB Python with kernel Python 3 doesn't seem to detect it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code from the video:

[image]

Code from the question:

[image]

As I have commented earlier, indentation matters!

In general, a better tutorial on this matter might be https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/How_To_Compute_Mandelbrodt_Set_Quickly?lang=en which has nice explanations of efficiency optimizations.